# Selecting Arabic words from mysql database using android application

Tags: android, utf-8, arabic, genymotion

I have an android application and i have connected it to a mysql database 
The database contain arabic words, When i select these words from the database arabic words will be decayed as shown bellow in the image

[image]

the result must be like this

```
sho = فەفف
hawkar= Array
nechir= Array
test= Array
```

And as show bellow the Collation of my database is utf8_general_ci like shown bellow arabic words dosn't have any problem within the table
[image]

And this is the code of background works

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String login_url="http://kurddic.site88.net/login2.php";

    String method=params[0];
    if(method.equals("register")){

    }
    else if(method.equals("login")){

        try {
            URL url=new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));

            String response="";
            String line="";

            while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null) {
                response+=line;
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return response;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

And this is the php selection code

```
<?php
require "config.php";
$sql_query = "select en,ku from words where active='1'";
$result=mysql_query($sql_query);
if($qq=mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$name=$row["en"];
$name2=$row["ku"];
echo $name."= ".$name2;
echo"<br/>";
}

}
else{
echo "no info is available";
}
?>
```

Note that iam using [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) emulator
Is the problem is with my emulator or what? 

Thanks for any help....

Comment: show some arbitrary arabic text on dialog in your emulator to check if the problem is Genymotion

Comment: it dosn't have any problem

Comment: please post your code that gets data from mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit **your code**:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Thanks , i have not noticed that